# How to install caffe library on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, caffe

I can't install Python Caffe Library on Windows. I tried everything but at best caffe library gets installed but "does not see" numpy library even if it is installed. What should I do?

Comment: If it gets installed, did you try importing it?

Comment: Yes, I did it but it does not work anyway